# MicroPython socket not serving iPhone safari browser on Raspberry Pi Pico W

Tags: sockets, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I am running a simple server on a Raspberry Pi Pico W, and I can connect to the server just fine using Firefox on Windows. However, when trying to connect from my iPhone using Safari or Firefox neither works. The request is received, and it actually sends three identical requests.

```py
import network
import socket
from time import sleep

def connect():
    #Connect to WLAN
    wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
    wlan.active(True)
    wlan.connect("ssid", "password")
    while wlan.isconnected() == False:
        print('Waiting for connection...')
        sleep(1)
    ip = wlan.ifconfig()[0]
    print(f"Connection established on IP {ip}")
    return ip
def open_socket(ip):
    # Open a socket
    address = (ip, 80)
    connection = socket.socket()
    connection.bind(address)
    connection.listen(16)
    print(address)
    return connection

def serve(connection):
    #Start a web server
    while True:
        client = connection.accept()[0]
        request = client.recv(4096)
        request = str(request)
        print(request)
        html = "Simple text for debugging"
        client.send(html)
        client.close()


ip = connect()
connection = open_socket(ip)
print(connection)
serve(connection)
```

The three requests received by the server from Safari are identical: `b'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 10.1.10.144\r\nUpgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 16_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.3 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1\r\nAccept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n'` 
Is there some setting that needs to be specified with socket for it to work with Safari?

I have tried setting the port to 443 in case it was an issue with iOS not accepting http sites, but not only did that not work, but it made the page not load in Firefox.

Comment: You don't speak proper HTTP in your server.  Firefox and Chrome might interpret your broken response as HTTP/0.9, Safari might reject it because it is broken.  I recommend you learn more about HTTP first - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#HTTP/1.1_example_of_request_/_response_transaction

Comment: *"I have tried setting the port to 443 in case it was an issue with iOS not accepting http sites,"* - sites don't magically turn into https by changing the port. HTTPS is HTTP over TLS, i.e. there need to be much more done than changing the port. I recommend that you get a basic understanding of what HTTP, HTTPS and TLS is first.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I fixed the issue by concatenating `'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n'` to the beginning of my response string.